# Android studio shows "MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API." but it also shows "Inspection of the code found nothing to report."

Tags: android, android-studio

I am updating a project from 2 years ago to search for obsolete code and update it, it compiles without problems but I receive this warning:

> Note:
> C:\Users\PCDELL\AndroidStudioProjects\BM\app\src\main\java\p\p\bm\MainActivity.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for
> details.

I tried to search for deprecated code like I did before: Code>Analyze code>Run Inspection By name>Deprecated API usage>Ok but at the end it doesn't show anything, only this notification:

> Code inspection did not find anything to report. 90 files processed in
> 'Project "BM"'

So how can I find the deprecated code? because parsing shows no results and in MainActivity nothing is underlined as obsolete.

**Update**

I added the following in gradle and now I can see the deprecated methods, if someone knows how to do it in another way, your help will be welcome

```
allprojects {
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

}

In >=Android Studio Arctic Fox:

```
android {
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try in App/build.gradle change this and change the API of compile:

```
compileSdk 32
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yourapp.id"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner" android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

The problem also can be with the device that the API is deprectaed. So if this is the case you should reinstall also a new emulator with a higher API, for example to this APP a API 30.